# Symfony Api Platform return data not converted to hydra response

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com

I use API platform in my application, I create my custom  Paginator of API platform but the response is not converted to hydra response :

code repository:

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator as Paginator;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as DoctrinePaginator;

public function findByExampleField($page, $items)
{
    $firstResult = ($page - 1) * $items;

    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');

    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery()
        ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
        ->setMaxResults($items);


    $dp = new DoctrinePaginator($query);
    $po = new Paginator($dp);

    return $po;
}
```

with this code, the response is normale data and not hydra response

Comment: looks *almost* like https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/#custom-controller-action but ultimately, it's different. maybe you want to recreate it more closely... ? Specifically, the sample code on that link doesn't call getQuery ...

Comment: @Jakumi also return datas directly et not hydra response

Comment: Do you have Content-Type application/ld+json header?

Comment: @shvv yes I add application/ld+json to header but also error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? What does your custom paginator add to the existing one ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: @rugolinifr for example I have invoke all datas with status is true , here I create my custom function in repository and in controller i use this function

Answer (score 0):

Based on the *comment* section, since you want to extend a GET collection operation, I think creating a custom paginator is not a good approach:

- creating a custom paginator is **not** [mentionned as a way to extend Api-Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extending/#extending-api-platform),
- the use of customized queries is achieved by the [extension](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/) system.

**Example with the *extension* system:**

(Note the operation name)

```php
// src/Entity/Data.php

namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations = {
 *          "get_only_status_true" = {
 *              "method" = "get"
 *          }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DataRepository::class)
 */
class Data
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $status;
    
    // getter and setters there
}
```

```php
// src/Doctrine/DataExtensions.php

namespace App\Doctrine;

class DataExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface
{
    public function applyToCollection(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator,
                                      string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
        if ($resourceClass === Data::class && $operationName === 'get_only_status_true') {
            $data = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
            $queryBuilder->andWhere("$data.status = 1");
        }
    }
}
```